# sending a two dimension array from JavaScript to php and vice versa

Tags: php, javascript, json

i use this code to send one dimension array of integer but how to make it sending and receiving two dimension array formed by combination of integer and string e.g. [number here]["text here"] but the url has a limit so that i can't make a big array

```
//Send data to php
                var queryString ="?";
                            for(var t=0;t<alldays.length;t++)
                                {   
                                    if(t==alldays.length-1)
                                    queryString+="arr[]="+alldays[t];
                                    else
                                    queryString+="arr[]="+alldays[t]+"&";
                                }
                ajaxRequest.open("POST", "forbidden.php" + queryString, true);
                ajaxRequest.send(null); 

            }

// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server(sended as echo json_encode($array))
    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

        var myArray = ajaxRequest.responseText.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace(/"/g,"").split(",");
        for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) { alldays[i] = parseInt(myArray[i]); } 

        }}
```

Comment: respond or accept an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of including the request as a query string added to the url, send it as the body of the POST:

```
var queryString ="";
for(var t=0;t<alldays.length;t++)
{
    if(t==alldays.length-1)
        queryString+="arr[]="+alldays[t];
    else
        queryString+="arr[]="+alldays[t]+"&";
}
ajaxRequest.open("POST", "forbidden.php", true);
ajaxRequest.send(queryString);
```

There aren't the same restrictions on the query length if its sent as the POST body.

However, all your POST variables are named `"arr[]"`, which is going to cause problems. I suggest the following encoding scheme instead:

```
var queryString = "n=" + alldays.length;
for (var t=0; t<alldays.length; t++)
{
    queryString += "&arr_" + t + "=" + alldays[t];
}
ajaxRequest.open("POST", "forbidden.php", true);
ajaxRequest.send(queryString);
```

Then on the server you can retrieve the number of array elements with `$_POST["n"]` and then process `$_POST["arr_" + t]` for each `t` from 0 to `n-1`.

Comment: @user1874258 - Your post names are all named `"arr[]"`, and none are named `"arr"`. I added a suggestion for dealing with this.

Answer (score 0):

You do use a `POST` request - so don't send the array in the `GET` parameters of the query string!

```
var queryString =""; // no question mark
// construct rest of query string here
ajaxRequest.open("POST", "forbidden.php", true);
ajaxRequest.send(queryString);
```

Also, use JSON for the response. PHP-side: [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), JavaScript-side: [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)